# Which JOIN is correct to use when using FUNCTION?

Tags: t-sql

Take this sample code...

```
SELECT Persons.name,
       getCarModelID(Persons.ID) AS car_model -- < A function 

FROM   Persons
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Cars ON getCarModelID(Persons.ID) = Cars.ID
```

In the sample above, is it correct to use "LEFT OUTER JOIN"?

Comment: Use of Left Outer join or any other kind of join totally depends upon what kind of data you want. It's completely subjective.

Comment: That depends on the expected result

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to join a table with a function then you will need to use the T-SQL "Outer Apply" operator. Similar to Left Join you used and the above will be possible.

Joins can only join two or more tables but not a table with a function. 
You can [learn using Apply from this link.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

The correct code will be as:

```
SELECT Persons.name,
       getCarModelID(Persons.ID) AS car_model -- < A function 

FROM   Persons
       OUTER APPLY Cars ON getCarModelID(Persons.ID) = Cars.ID;
```